# How to get Tweets of a single user?

Tags: c#, api, twitter, stream

How do I get tweets of a single user? I know that I have to use the Twitter Streaming API. URL I should use is

```
https://userstream.twitter.com/1.1/user.json
```

but how do I say which user's tweets I want to get? I tried

```
https://userstream.twitter.com/1.1/USERNAME.json
```

but this is not working.

Are there any parameters?

EDIT:
I found the "track"-parameter. Does this work? If I want to get Tweets of "HarryPotter" can I use this URL?

```
https://userstream.twitter.com/1.1/user.json#track=@harrypotter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use  [GET statuses/user_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline) with screen_name=USERNAME, but I have no idea what you really want to do.